# How does the healing jutsu work?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, when the medical team starts to heal wounds, they use their chakra. Does this only heal and restore chakra, or does it also help regenerate the skin cut by kunais?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Medical ninjutsu can be used to heal wounds, such as those cause by kunai. It is used for a number of purposes, including:

- Healing: [Healing Chakra Transmission](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Chakra_Transmission), [Healing Resuscitation Regeneration Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Resuscitation_Regeneration_Technique)
- Treating internal and external injuries: [Mystical Palm Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mystical_Palm_Technique)
- Treating poisons: [Delicate Illness Extraction Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Delicate_Illness_Extraction_Technique)
- Performing autopsy or surgery: [Chakra Scalpel](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra_Scalpel)
- Healing oneself: [Creation Rebirth](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Creation_Rebirth), [Strength of a Hundred Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Strength_of_a_Hundred_Technique)
- Offensively in several ways: [Body
  Pathway
  Derangement](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Body_Pathway_Derangement),
  [Poison Mist Needle
  Shot](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Poison_Mist_Needle_Shot).

Answer (score 5):

**How does the healing jutsu work?**

It works by channeling the healer's chakra into the patient's body, in order to help the regeneration of skin, cells, chakra flow, etc. The medical-nin can also use medical ninjutsu in himself. This type of technique requires great chakra control, because excessive infusion of chakra may cause unwanted problems. Healing jutsu have a wide range of uses, such has physical injury healing, poison healing, or even offensive uses.

**Does it also help regenerate the skin cut by kunais?**

Yes, there are some examples:

- The [Mystical Palm Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mystical_Palm_Technique) helps in the regeneration of injuries, both internal and external. This technique requires great chakra control, for excess of chakra infused can drive the patient into a comatose state. For this same reason, this technique can also be used as an offensive technique (as seen in chapter 103, pages 9-10, when Kabuto used it against Kiba). This technique's usage has been seen (among others) in chapter 296, pages 12-13, when Kabuto (who can use this technique effectively at a distance) healed Sakura's wounds (caused by Naruto in [Four-tailed form](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki%27s_Jinch%C5%ABriki_Forms#Version_2)). Also, in chapter 297, Sakura heals Naruto's skin after it had been damaged by the Kyuubi cloak.
- Also, Tsunade's [Mitotic Regeneration](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Creation_Rebirth) is able to regenerate physical injuries, at the cost of reducing her lifespan. We've seen her heal herself after she was trespassed by Orochimaru, using the Kusanagi sword, in chapter 169. After having been inflicted these wounds that would otherwise have been fatal, she regenerated herself fully, eliminating every cut in her body.
- There are also [techniques that can resuscitate](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Resuscitation_Regeneration_Technique), healing the injured body parts in the process. This was the technique used when reviving and healing Neji (chapter 235, page 9), after his fight with Kidomaru. In this fight, Neji was trespassed by an arrow (with considerable diameter), that brought about his collapse. With regular healing techniques, such as the Mystical Palm Technique, the healing of such wounds would've been impossible.